# How to reduce delay in playing sound on mobile web app

Tags: javascript, web-applications, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a web prototype of a mobile app.

My code is like

```
var eat = new Audio("snd/home/eating.mp3");
$('#eatBtn').live("click", function(){
    eat.play()
});
```

The problem here is that, although the Audio plays, on Safari for iPhone, there's usually a huge delay from the time the button is pressed to the time the audio starts playing. The size of the audio files are usually less than 50kb.

Is there any way to minimize the time slack or any method to optimize my code?

Comment: Just a thought, haven't tried html5 audio, but if you can preload the player right at the start and play a blank noise, then send other files to it it may be faster. I'm guessing the latency is the loading of bringing up the audio decoder.

Comment: how long is the 'huge' delay like ?

Comment: the delay is like a couple of secs (maybe 3 to 5 secs) but it's weird when in use.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem in my app, and for what it's worth here is the answer from another SO post:

[Audio delay on HTML5 mobile web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778277/audio-delay-on-html5-mobile-web-app)

It describes the cause of the problem, but not a solution unfortunately.